# Speed up getting all products using Shopify API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, shopify

Right now I am this code to get an array of all products in the users store:

```
# Write loop to get all if more than 1 page
@store_products = []
page = 1

while 1

  products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 250, :page => page, :fields=> "id,title,images"})

  break if products.length == 0

  products.each do |product|
    @store_products << product
  end

  page = page + 1

end
```

However, if the store has 4000+ products it slows down the app's loading time dramatically and sometimes times out. Is there a better way of doing this. And also, is it possible to use Redis to cache the array of products or the products individually? Would this even be beneficial? I have been trying to do that with marginal speed improvements so far, if any.

Here's how I'm doing that in the view's script:

```
<% products_to_cache = @store_products.to_json.html_safe %>

<% cache(products_to_cache) do %>
    var products = <%= products_to_cache %>;
<% end %>
```

Comment: You should never, ever do external requests synchronous in a rails app (or in any other app for that matter). Make this a background job and push the projects to the client when done or preload the information using a cron job.

Comment: @Oleander how would I push the store_products to the view after getting it in the background job? Assuming I am using sidekiq.

Comment: Let the background job populate the cache and then push the information to the client using websocket

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ShopifyAPI is over HTTP, you could use the [typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) to perform the external API calls in parallel.

Although it might produce a significant performance bump, note that you won't be able to use the `ShopifyAPI` client - you'll need to construct the requests using `typhoeus`.